# Trouble Building APK with flet: Stuck at Packaging Python App; ImportError with Argon2 on Mobile Transfer

Tags: python, flet

I am attempting to build an APK from my app. I've added these libraries to requirements.txt: flet, pyotp, argon2-cffi, cryptography, mysql-connector-python. However, when I run the command "flet build apk," it gets stuck at packaging the Python app.

I tried running "flet build windows," and it builds the app normally. Additionally, when I only include flet and pyotp in requirements.txt, the app builds successfully. However, when I transfer the app to my phone, I encounter a traceback indicating "no module found: argon2."